# Batch redirect stderr with other info

Tags: windows, batch-file, stderr

I need to launch a jar file (of which I don't have the sources, so I can't modify it) on multiple files. The code looks like this:

```
for %%f in (%inputFolder%*) do ( 
    java -jar MyJar.jar %%f 2>>%errorFile%
)
```

Now the problem is if MyJar.jar ends with exceptions on multiple files, in the error files I can only see a bunch of exceptions, without being able to identify the file which caused them.

Is there a way to append to the error file also the file `%%f` before the exception, to have something like this:

```
File a.txt
exception...

File b.txt
exception...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the errors to a separate file first and then check if it has any contents:

```
for %%f in (%inputFolder%*) do ( 
    del tmp.err
    set has_err=
    java -jar MyJar.jar %%f 2>> tmp.err
    set /p has_err=<tmp.err
    if defined has_err (
        echo %%f >> %errorFile%
        echo.-------------------------------
        type tmp.err >> %errorFile%
        echo.
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes but this will add every single file name to the error file. This is what I'm doing atm, but i would prefer to change this to something better if it's acheivable

Comment: I've updated my answer to only add headers for runs that have errors.